# K-means classification

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, k-means

I have a data set which I know has 3 classes. Say I want to perform k-means classification on this data set, with k=10. I would obtain 10 clusters. How would I merge these 10 clusters into the 3 classes, and based on what rules would I do this (e.g. distance metrics)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could run k-means again on your clusters, this time setting k=3. Or you could perform expectation maximization on them. Or you could go with brute force and test all the 120 ways of merging 10 clusters into 3.

The correct way of doing things would be to set k=3 from the outset. A k-means solution with the wrong set of classes could be a very poor fit.

Comment: It might be that the data has 3 classes but splitted in 10 different regions, so running Kmeans with K=3 won't work since it uses the closest centroid for classification. For example, the XOR problem has 2 classes but it won't work with K=2, you need K=4 and then extra merging.

Comment: Seems like the merging logic would be entirely problem-dependent, then.